# How to split existing blog into Wordpress Multisites without breaking links?

Tags: multisite, redirect, multi-language

I am going to split an existing Wordpress blog with a lot of posts in different languages into [multisites](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) which get all posts of one language each.

The multisites will be available under different subdomains then. For example `en.example.com`, `de.example.com` and `fr.example.com`. So the URL of all existing articles will change. This is an issue because the old links are indexed by Google and linked by other pages.

Does the multisite feature handle old links e.g. `www.example.com/an-english-article` by redirecting to the new article e.g. `en.example.com/an-english-article`? It would be great if the server could send `301 Moved Permanently` responses so that Google can update their index accordingly.

How is this handled by Wordpress multisite, and if it isn't properly, how can I set up 301 codes and redirects to the new article by a plugin or even by hand?